# How to get the part of content with javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to get the content of markdown files from remote server with javascript `fetch`.
Before downloading full text of the files, I want to check their front matter to determine to download each file. An example markdown file is like:

```
---
author: foobar
---

very long text...
```

I know I can download the full content of the file, but I want to get the first part of the content to reduce the network load.

How to download the part of the markdown file?

Comment: what is "front matter" ?

Comment: The header surrounded by `---` in the example. See here: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/

Comment: remember that as Jekyll is a generator, on production, you will not have access to the markdown files, but the ones generated by it, so, only the full HTML...

Comment: Write a plugin that generates metadata files as part of the jekyll conversion pass. Then load _those_ instead of trying to start a download that you then need to abort before the file itself is done based on some content byte sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would recommend serving the metadata as a separate resource, you can abort an ongoing fetch using an [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort):

```js
const controller = new AbortController(),
signal = controller.signal;

fetch(url, {signal}).then(async resp => {
  const reader = resp.body.getReader();

  // Read the front matter. This example just reads 100 bytes.
  let bytesRead = 0;
  let result, data = [];
  while (true) {
    // Note: It is possible for `reader.read()` to return the whole file
    // if the HTTP response is not split among several TCP packets.
    result = await reader.read();
    if (result.done)
      break;
    
    data.push(result.value);
    bytesRead += result.value;
    if (bytesRead >= 100)
      break;
  }

  console.log(data);

  controller.abort();
});
```